# How can we choose the identity element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $\mathbb{R}^{*}=R\setminus \left \{ 0 \right \}$. Consider maps $f_{i}:\mathbb{R}^{*}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{*}$:

$f_{1}(x)=x, f_{2}(x)=\frac{1}{x},f_{3}(x)=-x,f_{4}(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$.
There is a binary operation (called $S$) *  satisfied: $f_{i}$*$f_{j}$=$f_{i}.f_{j}$

Prove that,  the maps above is a group and the group is commutative.

---

I supposed $e=f_{1}$, but $\forall f_{i} $, choose $i=3$ then $e*f_{3}=f_{3}*e=-x^{2}\neq f_{3}$, I also got trouble with $i=1,2,4$. Please help me, thank you very much!

My problem is, with the definition about the set of $f_{i}$, how can we choose the identity element?

Comment: Are you sure of the definition of the law $*$ ? Is it really a multiplication, and not a composition ? As stated, the four maps don't form a group for $*$.

Comment: I think your binary operation is $f_i(f_j(x))$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, I had the same question as you, maybe this is an mistake of my book. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually its $f_1 * f_3(x) = f_1(f_3(x)) = f_1(-x) = -x = f_3(x)$.

It is not $f_1(x)×f_3(x)$, which is what you did.

In fact $f_1$ is indeed the identity element.